# C++ Template: cannot find base class type parameter method when overloaded

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Please consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual void foo(std::string str) = 0;
  void foo() { foo("LOL"); }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void foo(std::string str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; }
};

template<class T> class MyTemplate {
public:
  void print() { a.foo(); }
  T a;
};

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  MyTemplate<Derived> a;
  a.print();
}
```

When compiling, I have the following error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void MyTemplate<T>::print() [with T = Derived]’:
main.cpp:24:11:   required from here
main.cpp:16:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::foo()’
   void print() { a.foo(); }
                  ^
main.cpp:16:18: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:11:8: note: virtual void Derived::foo(std::string)
   void foo(std::string str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; }
        ^
main.cpp:11:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

It found that the solution is to write:

```
  void print() { a.Base::foo(); }
```

But why is that ? Why can't G++ find the Base::foo() method on it's own ?

Thanks

Comment: Because `a.foo()` does not take any argument, but your `Derived class` function `foo()` is taking `string` as an argument.

Comment: @Klaus I guess it is not that dupe...

Comment: @EdgarRokyan: Yepp, you are right. Removed comment and vote... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that method `foo` in class `Derived` hides all methods with the same name which are inherited from class `Base`. Consequently, only a single version of method `foo` which accepts `std::string` as parameter is available for a call through `Derived`. As a result you have to call `foo` which accepts no arguments explicitly using the syntax:

```
a.Base::foo();
```

Note, that you can also use [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) to make inherited `foo` visible in `Derived` class:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  using Base::foo;
  void foo(std::string str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; }
};
```

With this change the next code becomes valid:

```
a.foo();
```